# Disabling version suffix/extension in autoconf or makefile

Tags: java, linux, makefile, shared, autoconf

Currently large library i am compiling on Linux outputs shared library as:

libxxx1.1.so.0.0.0

Problem arises when i try to load it in java's System.loadLibrary(..);

What can i do to make compiled so be simple libxxxx.so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the `libtool` [`-avoid-version`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Link-mode.html) flag... assuming you are using `libtool` for this.